# How to use an S4 method in an object-oriented way

Tags: r, r-s4

In high-programming languages a public function of an arbitrary class could be executed by a call of an instance of this class (object), e.g. `a=new Foo(); a.somePublicFunction();` If I want to use this programming paradigm in R, I would write the following code:

```
 setClass(Class = "Foo",
          representation = representation(a="numeric")
 ) 
 Foo<-function(a=1){new("Foo",a=a)}
 myFunction.Foo<-function(object){
    return(object@a)
 }
 setGeneric("myFunction", function(object) standardGeneric("myFunction"))
 setMethod("myFunction", signature = "Foo", definition = myFunction.Foo)
```

Why is it possible to override `myFunction` simply with `myFunction<-1/3`? If I would call `myFunction(obj)`, where `obj is an object of class`Foo`, the interpreter should refer to`myFunction.Foo`. How to handle this problem in R?

Answer (score 1):

Typically classes and methods are defined in a package. Packages have a (locked) name space in which the symbols are defined. The user can redefine any symbol, but do this in the global environment; the underlying symbol is still accessible. In base R:

```
> pi
[1] 3.141593
> pi = "apple"
> pi
[1] "apple"
> base::pi
[1] 3.141593
```

Or a little more subtly, showing that R knows about functions versus variables

```
> log(1:5)
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379
> log = "pine"
> log
[1] "pine"
> log(1:5)
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379
```

The underlying understanding of what is going on involves environments (of which a name space is a special case), the `search()` path, and R's association of symbol with value in an environment. Symbols must be unique in an environment (hence your `myFunction <- 1/3` over-writes your previous definition of `myFunction` in the global environment). Symbols can be found dynamically along the search path (as returned by `search()`, or in a more complicated way within a package that looks first in the package name space, then in the base environment, then along the user-visible search environment).